# Signature field name limitations

Tags: itext, field, signature, itext7

during our initial tests with itext7, we discovered that dots are not accepted inside signature field names(itext5 never complained about that).
Unfortunately we cannot ask our customers to change the way they call signature fields inside their pdfs.

So, is there a way to bypass this behavior? And what is the reason behind this decision?

Thank you very much

AM

Comment: This sounds like a customer question. Customers shouldn't post questions on Stack Overflow. They should use the closed ticketing system instead. Use the login information that was shared with you when you purchased your support contract. Using Stack Overflow for commercial support questions isn't allowed by Stack Exchange.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support